# How to make an AWS website to display and update S3 contents?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to find a simple way to create a dynamic website that displays the contents of my S3 bucket and allows me to drag new content into the bucket through the website. All the content will be .BIN files. The end goal is to be able to click on any of these files, have it processed by a lambda function, and have the analysis be displayed on the website.

I don't have any experience with AWS or web development, other than the time I've spent learning about AWS thus far. I think I need to use Gateway API but I'm not sure what to do with the URL it creates once I deploy it. The tutorials I've found haven't been super clear to me so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, AWS is complicated, you need to get used to that if you want to use it. There is no *easy* way to achieve this, all involve a couple different services, connecting them, granting appropriate permissions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To make a static website, you can deploy a static website in S3:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html

Then you can make a lambda function to get a pre-signed URL to upload a file to S3.

[Uploading objects using pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

You can make another lambda function to fetch and display files and analysis.